# What is the root morpheme of a word when 'y' turns into 'ies' or 'ier'?

Tags: morphemes

Suppose I have to write out the root morpheme and the bound morpheme. Consider the word 'happier'.

I've seen some examples, for example here on the second slide: http://www.slideshare.net/mobile/fatmasima/morphology-son where the root is 'happy' and the bound morpheme is 'er'.

However, on another website (I forgot the link but I will post it if I find it), the example was 'prettier' and it mentioned that the root was 'pretti' and the bound morpheme was 'er'.

My question is, when y turns into ier or ies (for example supplies or prettier), what is the root and bound morpheme?

Comment: I'd have thought morphemes are the building blocks of *real* (i.e. - *spoken*) language. So it doesn't really matter if a written representation changes from **y** to **i** before tacking on a bound inflectional morpheme. That's just spelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammar.about.com has several [examples](http://grammar.about.com/od/d/g/Derivational-Morpheme.htm) of root morphemes in compounds like this:  beauty+-ful giving beautiful; happy+ness giving happiness.  The spelling apparently is the spelling of the root word itself, not the word as it is after spelling changes used when attaching an affix.